# How to check if any parameter exists in list of parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to check if any parameter exists in list of parameters

I can check this way

```
if (params.has_key?(:first) || params.has_key?(:second) || params.has_key?(:third) ||
        params.has_key?(:fourth) || params.has_key?(:fifth) || params.has_key?(:sixth))
```

Is there any other way to check this instead repeating `params.has_key?` for each param?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
if (params.keys & %i(first second third fourth fifth sixth)).any?
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it like this:

```
if [:first, :second, :third, :fourth, :fifth, :sixth].any? { |key| params.has_key? key }
```

or slighly fancier:

```
if %i{first second third fourth fifth sixth}.any? &params.method(:has_key?)
```

Comment: You could use `key?` instead of `has_key?`. `method()` syntax is quite nice.